# log4j don't log after redeploy

Tags: java, log4j2, tomcat9

We have common configuration for `log4j2.xml` under `catalina` base directory. so all the modules under `webapps` use this configuration. Also `log4j-core`, `log4j-web` and `log4j-api` libraries under shared lib of tomcat. When we restart the tomcat all the modules wrote their logs. But when redeploy any of them only that module logs others not. For example we have `A`,`B` and `C` module under the webapps folder. If we redeploy `C` module after restart then we see only `C` module logs. How can I solve this problem? I could not found any reson why this happen

I enabled the `log4j` logs to see what is happening. After redeploy `log4j` print this kind of logs

```
2021-04-13 17:40:56,930 Catalina-utility-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=457e2f02
2021-04-13 17:40:56,930 Catalina-utility-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=457e2f02,component=StatusLogger
2021-04-13 17:40:56,930 Catalina-utility-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=457e2f02,component=ContextSelector
2021-04-13 17:40:56,930 Catalina-utility-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=457e2f02,component=Loggers,name=
```

`457e2f02` this should be the our module name but why `log4j` print random text

`log4j2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG" monitoring="10">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log.level">ALL</Property>
        <Property name="framework.log.level">WARN</Property>
        <Property name="file.pattern">%d{DEFAULT}: [%level{WARN=WAR, DEBUG=DBG, ERROR=ERR, TRACE=TRC, INFO=INF, FATAL=FTL}] %-c.%M[%L] - %m%n</Property>
        <Property name="console.pattern">%highlight{%d{DEFAULT}: [%level{WARN=WAR, DEBUG=DBG, ERROR=ERR, TRACE=TRC, INFO=INF, FATAL=FTL}] %-c.%M[%L] - %m%n \n}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red bold, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green bold, DEBUG=white bold, TRACE=cyan}</Property>
        <Property name="logs.dir">logs</Property>
        <Property name="app.name">magus</Property>
        <Property name="script.test.mode">false</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${console.pattern}"/>
        </Console>
    <Socket name="GELF" protocol="tcp" host="graylog.host" port="12201">
            <!-- gelf tcp does not support compression-->
            <GelfLayout includeStackTrace="true" host="${hostName}" includeThreadContext="true" includeNullDelimiter="true"
                  compressionType="OFF">

                <KeyValuePair key="host" value="${hostName}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="version" value="1.1"/>
                <!--<KeyValuePair key="short_message" value="$${event:Message}"/>--><!--   not required             -->
                <!--<KeyValuePair key="application_name" value="$${ctx:application}"/>-->
                <KeyValuePair key="thread_id" value="$${event:ThreadId}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="thread_name" value="$${event:ThreadName}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="timestamp" value="$${event:Timestamp}"/>
                <!--<KeyValuePair key="level" value="1"/>--><!-- default level type is number so we don't use-->
                <KeyValuePair key="log_level" value="$${event:Level}"/><!-- for readabilty and filtering-->
            </GelfLayout>
        </Socket>
        <RollingFile name="LOG" fileName="${logs.dir}/${app.name}.log"
                     filePattern="${logs.dir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/${app.name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${file.pattern}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3">
                <!--
                Nested conditions: the inner condition is only evaluated on files
                for which the outer conditions are true.
                -->
                <Delete basePath="${logs.dir}" maxDepth="2" testMode="${script.test.mode}">
                    <IfFileName glob="*/${app.name}*.log.gz">
                        <IfLastModified age="90d">
                            <IfAny>
                                <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="10"/>
                            </IfAny>
                        </IfLastModified>
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LOG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref='GELF' />
        </Root>

        <Logger name="xxx.project" level="${log.level}"/>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="${framework.log.level}"/>
        <Logger name="com.zaxxer" level="${framework.log.level}"/>
        <!--<Logger name="org.hibernate" level="ALL"/>-->
        <Logger name="org.reflections" level="OFF"/>
    <!-- show executed queries -->
        <!--<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"/>-->
        <!-- show query params -->
    <!--
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE"/> -->
        <!--
        <AsyncLogger name="az.sanco.projects.ais.server.filter" additivity="false" level="${log.level}">
            <AppenderRef ref="AUDITOR"/>
        </AsyncLogger> -->
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Tomcat version: 9.0

Java version: 1.8

log4j2 version: 2.14.0

Comment: Can you add the contents of `log4j2.xml` to your question? Do all your applications log to the same file?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz on development machine yes all the module log to the same file. Actually I don't think that the problem is related to `log4j2.xml` file because everything works normal when tomcat start. problem start after if redeploy any of module. But I will post the content of configuration

Comment: I can emulate your problem by removing all `log4j*` libraries from the applications' `WEB-INF/lib` folder: in this situation all applications use the same `LoggerContext` (with a hex identifier as yours) and `log4j-web` closes it on **any** application reload.

Comment: If you use the Log4j2 API directly, you should probably leave a copy of `log4j-api` in each application (it means each application will have "its own" `LogManager` class).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thank you very much. If you want add your comment as answer and I accepted as correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random name `457e2f02` of your [`LoggerContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html) suggests that all your applications are using a single context. When one of your applications is stopped, the [`stop`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html#stop-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method is called on the context and no further messages can be logged. Meanwhile the reloaded application creates a context for itself.

This can occur, if you are using the Log4j API directly in your applications, but you don't ship the applications with a copy of `log4j-api`: in this situation the `LogManager` class in the shared Tomcat classloader will be used by all applications.

Try adding `log4j-api.jar` to your applications.

Comment: While your answer is probably correct, that is not how the ClassLoaderContextSelector is supposed to work. It should be determining the classloader of the class calling getLogger and associating the logger with the LoggerContext for that classloader. If that is not happening then a bug should be reported.

Comment: Yes, I also thought that the `ContextSelector` should create a different context per classloader, but it is not true in practice. However calling `LogManager.getLogger` in a web application **without** adding `log4j-api` to `WEB-INF/lib` is probably not an acceptable scenario.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz should I move all `log4j-core`, `log4j-web` and `log4j-api` to all my application? When I only copy `log4j-api` to my applications and keep others on common place I got exception `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`. In this case should I copy all log4j jar to my application? what is the correct way of implementing log4j in our case. Because we did what documentation suggest but seems that it does not work properly

Comment: I would keep `log4j-api` and `log4j-web` in the application, while the default implementation `log4j-core` can remain in the common classloader.

Answer (score 1):

Actually @PiotrP.Karwasz answer solves the `log4j` problem. But don't solve our problem. If we applied him answer then we should move all `log4j-core`, `log4j-api`, and `log4j-web` jars to each of our applications `WEB-INF\lib` folder which is not efficient way. because we have almost 20 modules and in this case we copy jars to all these modules and occupies more resource. According [log seperation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html) documentation we should not do any further configuration for this requirements. Log4j context selector should choose context auto for each `war` modules. But in practice we saw that it does not work properly. Maybe bug or may be we did not configure correctly. I did the third option `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.JndiContextSelector` from documentation. And this solve our problems. We keep `log4j-core`, `log4j-api`, and `log4j-web` jars in common path and each of our modules use these jars. Now `log4j` works properly when we redeploy one of our module.